# SQL Union all throws SQL Syntax error but the two SELECTS are ok

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I want to join 2 SELECT statements. They both work fine individually but if I try to use the Union All I get a syntax error:

> [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '' at line 29

Which doesn't make any sense to me. I searched for that error message but I don't use quotes in that line (29 is UNION ALL)

```
SELECT NULL                                                        AS id,
       table_a.calendar_day                             AS
       calendar_day,
       'XXX'                                                       AS mbr_entity
       ,
       'total'                                                    AS
       product,
       'total'                                                    AS
       mbr_stock_category,
       'total'                                                    AS component,
       SUM(IF(table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', aim, 0))      AS aim,
       SUM(IF(table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', cf, 0))       AS cf,
       SUM(IF(table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', mbr, 0))      AS mbr,
       SUM(IF(table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', ytd, 0))      AS ytd,
       SUM(IF(table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', forecast, 0)) AS forecast,
       SUM(table_b.a
           + table_b.b
           + table_b.c
           + table_b.d
           + table_b.e)                    AS actual
FROM   table_a
       left join table_b
              ON table_b.calendar_day =
                 table_a.calendar_day
                 AND table_b.mbr_entity =
                     table_a.mbr_entity
WHERE MONTH(table_a.calendar_day) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
GROUP  BY calendar_day
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL                                                        AS id,
       table_a.calendar_day,
       table_a.mbr_entity,
       'total'                                                    AS product,
       'total'                                                    AS
       mbr_stock_category,
       'total'                                                    AS component,
       SUM(IF(table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', 0, aim))      AS aim,
       SUM(IF(table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', 0, cf))       AS cf,
       SUM(IF(table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', 0, mbr))      AS mbr,
       SUM(IF(table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', 0, ytd))      AS ytd,
       SUM(IF(table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', 0, forecast)) AS forecast,
       SUM(table_b.a
           + table_b.b
           + table_b.c
           + table_b.d
           + table_b.e)                    AS actual
FROM   table_a
       left join table_b
              ON table_b.calendar_day =
                 table_a.calendar_day
                 AND table_b.mbr_entity =
                     table_a.mbr_entity
WHERE  table_a.mbr_entity <> 'XXX'
AND MONTH(table_a.calendar_day) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
GROUP  BY calendar_day,
          mbr_entity
```

Comment: Wrap each subquery in parentheses.

Comment: the parentheses arn't the only problem @GordonLinoff his `SELECT` part queries also look like to be abusing MySQL's GROUP BY "feature"... By using columns in the SELECT which are not in the GROUP BY clause which is not valid ANSI GROUP BY SQL.

Comment: The parentheses were the problem. Thank you @GordonLinoff ! It works if I remove the where-clause without parentheses which is what confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Use Code Again

```
( SELECT NULL AS
    id,
    table_a.calendar_day AS calendar_day,
    'XXX' AS mbr_entity,
    'total' AS product,
    'total' AS mbr_stock_category,
    'total' AS component,
    SUM( IF ( table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', aim, 0 ) ) AS aim,
    SUM( IF ( table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', cf, 0 ) ) AS cf,
    SUM( IF ( table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', mbr, 0 ) ) AS mbr,
    SUM( IF ( table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', ytd, 0 ) ) AS ytd,
    SUM( IF ( table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', forecast, 0 ) ) AS forecast,
    SUM( table_b.a + table_b.b + table_b.c + table_b.d + table_b.e ) AS actual 
    FROM
        table_a
        LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_b.calendar_day = table_a.calendar_day 
        AND table_b.mbr_entity = table_a.mbr_entity 
    WHERE
        MONTH ( table_a.calendar_day ) = MONTH ( CURRENT_DATE ( ) ) 
    GROUP BY
        calendar_day 
    ) 
    UNION ALL
    (
    SELECT NULL AS
        id,
        table_a.calendar_day,
        table_a.mbr_entity,
        'total' AS product,
        'total' AS mbr_stock_category,
        'total' AS component,
        SUM( IF ( table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', 0, aim ) ) AS aim,
        SUM( IF ( table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', 0, cf ) ) AS cf,
        SUM( IF ( table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', 0, mbr ) ) AS mbr,
        SUM( IF ( table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', 0, ytd ) ) AS ytd,
        SUM( IF ( table_a.mbr_entity = 'XXX', 0, forecast ) ) AS forecast,
        SUM( table_b.a + table_b.b + table_b.c + table_b.d + table_b.e ) AS actual 
    FROM
        table_a
        LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_b.calendar_day = table_a.calendar_day 
        AND table_b.mbr_entity = table_a.mbr_entity 
    WHERE
        table_a.mbr_entity <> 'XXX' 
        AND MONTH ( table_a.calendar_day ) = MONTH ( CURRENT_DATE ( ) ) 
    GROUP BY
        calendar_day,
    mbr_entity 
    )
```

Comment: Or Send DB Example Attach